# Page (template) with only news of the type "gallery"

Tags: page-template, gallery, loop

Could anyone explain to me how to create a picture galleries page, using the built in Wordpress galleries (no plugins if possible)?

Basically, I would like to create a page (template?) in which I loop over all the news of the type Gallery.

I've seen some related questions, but without an answer. Could anyone be of service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'gallery' is a taxonomy item (like a category) you could create a new page template (perhaps based on index.php) and then use the [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function to return a list of posts in that category.

That's the process. Do you need more detail?

If 'gallery' is a post format that may be a quite different operation.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Yes, it is a category "gallery". Creating a new page template is not a problem, the actual PHP code for the get_posts() is another thing. Could you provide a little more detail?

Comment: Thank you, your views have set me in the right direction and have now found a suitable solution.

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Can you post your solution for the benefit of anyone landing here?